# How to get ColdFusion to do cfhttp post to site that uses GZIP

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using cfhttp to post data to a URL and getting "connection failure" as the file content. I've set the accept-encoding header to 'no-compression' which solves the problem for get requests [but not for posts](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1599-Campaign-Monitor-API-Connection-Failure-With-CFHTTP-And-GZIP-Compression.htm).

How do I successfully post when the site uses GZIP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gah. The problem was that Ben's CFHTTPSession component wasn't carrying the header over when doing redirects after a successful post. So my actual post was succeeding, but then the redirect was failing.

Fixing that in CFHTTPSession.cfc gotterdone

Answer (score 3):

http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm/2004/7/28/20040729

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*" />
<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these headers to your `<CFHTTP>` call:

```
<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
<cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
```

Source: http://coldfusion-archive.robgonda.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/12/30/cfhttp-and-gzip-compression/